# How to remove the start message of Gvim? And why my mark function does not work?

Tags: vim

[image]

When I open my Gvim under Windows, it gives above message. How to remove it?

The 2nd question is about the 'mark' function of Gvim.
By default, it should be installed together with Gvim and can be used after the installation. I did so in my own computer. But today when I do the same thing on my office computer, the 'mark' function does not work.

In my _vimrc file, I set below:

```
let mapleader=";"
```

So every time I just press ';' and then 'm' to activate mark function but failed.

Comment: When you combine two questions (which you normally shouldn't), please at least indicate why you think they belong together / have the same root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message box shows `:echomsg` output from both `cscope` and the *TagList* plugin. During GVIM startup, these appear in a message box popup, because the GUI hasn't yet been initialized.

The messages (at least the second; I don't understand Chinese) alert you about things that are missing on your system; you need to either install them (e.g. `ctags` from [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)), or uninstall / disable the corresponding plugin.

---

It looks that something similar applies to your second question: There is no built-in *mark function* accessible through mapleader; I think you mean a plugin that has to be installed separately (or copied from another system's `~/.vim/` folder).